# Configurar cPanel em servidor

Tags: dns, cpanel

Contratei um servidor clound com CentOs e Cpanel e um IP o cPanel ja vem instalado. Porem e preciso configurar o mesmo. Este e meu primeiro servidor portanto nunca fiz tal configuração. Estou com dificuldades pois não sei como apontar meu domínio para o servidor. na instalação do cPanel no passo 2 em Hostname coloquei: server.meudominio.com.br em Resolvers coloquei os padrões do google Primary: 8.8.8.8 Secundary: 8.8.4.4, em nameserver domains: ns1.meudominio.com.br ns2.meudominio.com.br em Add a Entries coloquei o ip do servidor na frente dos nameserver o restante utilizei tudo padrão.

Dae vem a duvida como apontar o meudominio.com.br para o servidor?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa ir onde seu domínio está registrado e mudar os DNSs dele para os DNSs da hospedagem. Não é no CPanel, é onde você comprou o domínio.

Comment: Ola marta. Obrigado por responder. A hospedagem no caso é esse servidor que contratei. como configurar as DNS dele?

Comment: Desculpe, ainda não entendi a pergunta. Sempre que você contrata uma hospedagem ou um servidor, ele te dá um DNS, mesmo que seja revenda. Isso já não vem configurado por padrão? É o IP, não é? O endereço onde a URL vai buscar a hospedagem. Então você tem de ir onde registrou o domínio e inserir esse endereço. Não sei se é algo que seja possível definir ou mudar. (ou estou falando besteira?)

Comment: pois então marta... sempre é assim. quando contratamos uma hospedagem ou uma revenda... esses serviços não atendem mais minha aplicação. contratei esse cloud da UOL mais só passei raiva ate o momento... suporte péssimo fica 50min tocando a musiquinha e quando atende cai a ligação. te falar nao e facil não.

Comment: @MarceloMartins, tem certeza que junto com a VPS da UOL vem com serviço de DNS? Não teria que contratar um usando algum provedor TLD .br (registro br ou redehost ou qualquer outro)? Em questão de VPS, recomendo soluções mais conhecidas como Amazon AWS ou Digital Ocean ou Linode, etc...

Comment: Ah, e usando um provedor de DNS, você precisa criar um registro do tipo `ADDRESS` do seu domínio para o IP externo público que a UOL te fornece. E em geral essas mudanças demoram um pouco para se propagar (12, 24 ou 48 horas).

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar os registros ns1.meudominio.com.br e ns2.meudominio.com.br no WHM >> Funções de DNS >> Add a Dns Zone e depois mudar o DNS do domínio para ns1.meudominio.com.br e ns2.meudominio.com.br.